# This HQL Query doesn't work with elements nor member of, but native query is ok

Tags: java

I have a problem running this HQL query:

```
@Query("select m from Mesa m where not exists (" +
      " from ValesMaster v " +
      " where v.cobrado = false " +
      " and v.id.fecha = :fecha " +
      " and m.id in elements(v.mesas)) " )
List<Mesa> getAvailableTables(@Param("fecha") Date fecha);
```

When I use this native query everything is OK:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT m.* from mesas m where not exists (" +
      "SELECT DISTINCT unnest(mesas) AS umesas FROM vales_master vm " +
      "WHERE cobrado = false AND fecha = :fecha and m.id = any(vm.mesas))", nativeQuery = true)
   List<Mesa> getAvailableTables(@Param("fecha") Date fecha);
```

But I wanto to use HQL. These are my entities Mesa:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mesas")
public class Mesa implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
   private Integer id;

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private Boolean activo;

   @Column(length = 16)
   private String nombre;

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private Boolean room;


   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="id_station")
   private Estacion estacion;

   public Mesa() {
   }

   public Integer getId() {
      return this.id;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public Boolean getActivo() {
      return this.activo;
   }

   public void setActivo(Boolean activo) {
      this.activo = activo;
   }

   public String getNombre() {
      return this.nombre;
   }

   public void setNombre(String nombre) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
   }

   public Boolean getRoom() {
      return this.room;
   }

   public void setRoom(Boolean room) {
      this.room = room;
   }

   public Estacion getEstacion() {
      return estacion;
   }

   public void setEstacion(Estacion estacion) {
      this.estacion = estacion;
   }
}
```

and ValesMaster:

```
@TypeDef(
        name = "string-array",
        typeClass = StringArrayType.class
)
@TypeDef(
        name = "int-array",
        typeClass = IntArrayType.class
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "vales_master")
public class ValesMaster implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @EmbeddedId
   private ValesMasterPK id;

   @Column(length = 128)
   private String cliente;

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private Boolean closed;

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private Boolean cobrado;

   @Column(name = "cod_vip_clients", length = 16)
   private String codVipClients;

   private Integer comensales;

   @Column(nullable = false, precision = 131089)
   @ColumnDefault("0.00")
   private BigDecimal descuento;

   @Column(name = "descuento_porciento", nullable = false, precision = 131089)
   @ColumnDefault("0.00")
   private BigDecimal descuentoPorciento;

   private Integer disco;

   private Integer foreigners;

   @Column(name = "id_cajero")
   private Integer idCajero;

   @Column(name = "id_dependiente")
   private Integer idDependiente;

   @Column(name = "id_payment")
   private Integer idPayment;

   @Column(nullable = false, precision = 131089)
   @ColumnDefault("0.00")
   private BigDecimal impuestos;

   @Column(name = "impuestos_porciento", nullable = false, precision = 131089)
   @ColumnDefault("0.00")
   private BigDecimal impuestosPorciento;

   @Column(name = "is_discount_percent", nullable = false)
   @ColumnDefault("true")
   private Boolean isDiscountPercent;

   @Column(name = "is_printed", nullable = false)
   @ColumnDefault("false")
   private Boolean isPrinted;

   @Type(type = "int-array")
   private int[] mesas;

   (...)
```

Any idea why this HQL Query give a "java.lang.NullPointerException" at build stage? The problem is with this section:

```
" and m.id in elements(v.mesas) ) "
```

And I think maybe is because int-array type definition, but I really want to work with my HQL Query. Any idea? member of doesn't work neither. BTW excuse my poor english. Is not my native language.

Thanks in advance,

CarlosM

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to end your @Query and your subquery. Try this and lets see what will happen next.

```
@Query("select m from Mesa m where not exists (" +
      " from ValesMaster v " +
      " where v.cobrado = false " +
      " and v.id.fecha = :fecha " +
      " and m.id in elements(v.mesas) )")
List<Mesa> getAvailableTables(@Param("fecha") Date fecha);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Not really friend this error was when i post it, I fix now, just as I have it and you suggest and yet it doesn´t work. Thanks anyway for your answer. If you look for lines down you will see this query last line just as you said...